# Having an error when importing Tensorflow into Python (Win7, Py3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, compiler-errors

The code I entered (To test if it works) was

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

but then it gave me this error in the shell when running it

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Obliveater95\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
>       fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])
>     File "C:\Users\Obliveater95\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
>       raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
>   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> te-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 54, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "C:\Users\Obliveater95\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Users\Obliveater95\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
>       import _pywrap_tensorflow
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "X:/Programs/My Programs/TensorFlow testing/Testing.py", line 1, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf
>     File "C:\Users\Obliveater95\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *
>     File "C:\Users\Obliveater95\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 60, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Obliveater95\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
>       fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])
>     File "C:\Users\Obliveater95\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
>       raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
>   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Obliveater95\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 54, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "C:\Users\Obliveater95\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Users\Obliveater95\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
>       import _pywrap_tensorflow
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
>
> Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
>   you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
>   please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
>   from there.

Help? And I'm new to Python so can you explain it simply? Ty.

Comment: Have you tried the instructions in the last paragraph?